# Do I need to consider endianness in this example?

Tags: c, endianness, unions

I am writing an encryption/decryption algo where I read blocks of **bytes** from a file, do my magic, then write those blocks back to the file.
Part of my algo uses a union. I stuff bytes into the bytes_io field, then suck them out again from the words_io field and apply some uint32_t bit mask.

```
union {
    uint32_t words_io[GKO_BLOCK_SIZE / sizeof(uint32_t)];
    uint8_t bytes_io[GKO_BLOCK_SIZE];                       
} transformOut;
```

I assume (and also my question,) that I need not worry about the platform endianness affecting the words I suck out of the word field of union since the union is really only storing the stream of bytes I shoved in there in the first place (and does not reorder them based on access.)

Am I correct here?

Comment: It would make a difference if you were reading the encrypted file onto a platform with a different endianness. Otherwise no.

Comment: @Deepstop. Help me understand. If I read a block of **bytes**, say 512 bytes from a file. endianness at this point is a non issue, Correct? If I then memcpy() the bytes into the union field bytes_io, endianness is still not in play. 
If I then pull a word from words_io, say words_io[0], you're saying endianness would come into play and the platform would rearrange the bytes?

Comment: If this is meant to work cross-platform, yes it matters.

Comment: [okay, thanks. That's what I was afraid of.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57538867/do-i-need-to-consider-endianness-in-this-example#comment101542954_57539272) --> I suspect  this fear is unfounded.  What is the concern?

Comment: @luket Depending on the library you're using, it should take care of the endianess problem by itself. If it is not, and you have access to the code, you can fix the problem yourself by doing `ntohl()` on each `words_io` element just before doing the encryption/decryption, and `htonl()` just after, as @chqrlie pointed out. This should overcome the endianess problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid your assumption is incorrect:

- the way the bytes read from the input and stored the `bytes_io` field of the union will be treated when read in blocks of 4 as `int32_t` values is definitely affected by the endianness of the system.

Imagine for example that your encryption technique is a simple exclusive or applied to elements of the `words_io` member. Unless the key happens to be symmetric for endianness, the result of the xor operation will be different on a little endian system and a big endian system. Applying this cypher in a big endian cellphone will be incompatible with the same code running on a little endian PC receiving the encrypted message.

If your cypher uses the array of `int32_t`, you must take steps to:

- read the input bytes into the `bytes_io` block and pad with the appropriate value for `GKO_BLOCK_SIZE` bytes.
- apply byte swapping to enforce a specified endianness to all words in the `words_io` array. For example using `ntohl()` after reading and `htonl()` before writing the bytes. This would be a no-op on big endian systems. Alternately, you can test the endianness with some other method and use `bswap32()` if it differs from the specified default.
- apply your cipher on the `words_io` array, either for encryption or decryption.
- apply byte swapping the opposite way, with `htonl()` or some other appropriate way.
- output the bytes from the `bytes_io` array.

Comment: okay, thanks. That's what I was afraid of.
How about if I simply cast my pointer to my byte array to a pointer to int32, then walk down the array applying my XOR every 4 bytes?

Comment: @luket: no difference, as a matter of fact, both methods invoke undefined behavior because of the strict aliasing rule. Using a `union` works with gcc because this compiler explicitly condones type pruning via unions, but the *official* way to do this is using `memcpy`.

Comment: Check my thinking here.
Because network-byte-order is the only constant, I can always convert the words I pull from words_io[] to network-byte-order via ntohl().
I am always reading bytes: So I read: "hello world, it's a sunny day" from disk to encrypt, then pull the **words** from words_io[] and then do ntohl(), then my transforms.
Decryptor runs&reads: the encrypted bytes-ignore endianness of current machine-into the byte buffer. We can again pull the bytes out from words_io[] and again do a ntohl(), converting to our known constant (to do decrypt xform.) 
Does this work?

Comment: Thanks chqrlie, you've been a big help.